# Best way to send massive push notification to GCM

Tags: php, android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I have to send Push Notifications with different messages for large number of devices (more than 50k devices simultaneously once a day)

I realized that stuff on APNS Service.
But in case of GCM i just a little bit confused.

What the best practice to realize that?
What if i loop through array of devices and messages and just shoot one by one via http?
Is that good idea?

I'm using PHP on my server side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What the best practice to realize that?

If they are truly different messages, you have no choice but to do them one at a time. While GCM supports up to a thousand devices per message, that's for the same message, not different ones.

> What if i loop through array of devices and messages and just shoot one by one via http? Is that good idea?

It should work.

That being said, you may wish to consider using the [GCM Cloud Connection Server (CCS)](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/ccs.html), which is a fancy way of saying "send the messages over XMPP using a long-lived socket instead of HTTP".

Comment: thanks a lot! Is there some good libraries to realize that "writing messages via XMPP" that you know?

Comment: @user2498233: I am sure there are some, but as I do not do Web development in PHP, I cannot name any -- sorry.